# Doubly Linked List - InsertAfter - Java

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

First of all, let me say that this is an assignment for a class where we have been tasked with writing our own doubly linked list class and **cannot use anything from Java SE (e.g. the LinkedList class)**. We have to make our code work with a provided driver class. I am not asking for anyone to do the homework for me, I am simply asking for some kind of clarification as to how exactly to implement these methods, since I have struggled with this on and off over the past few days.

We have been provided with an Interface, `textEditor.java` that provides methods which will be utilized by the driver class, `driver.java`. These methods include the typical `insert`, et. al. but my concern is the `insertAfter(int lineNum, E line)` method and its counterpart, `insertBefore`. I have not been able to get these to work because comparing `int` to `E`, despite my best efforts and reading through several Java texts for guidance.

Below is the code in the `DoublyLinkedList.java` file, as provided at onset. I would like to know how I can implement some kind of indexing and checking in order to be able to make an insertion *following* or *preceding* the line entered by the user/driver class.

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<E> implements TextEditor<E>
{
    Node<E> head, tail;

    public DoublyLinkedList()
    {       
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (head == null);  
    }

    public void insert(E line)
    {

    }   

    public void insertAfter(int lineNum, E line)
    {

    }

    public void insertBefore(int lineNum, E line) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
    {

    }

    public void deleteByPosition(int position)
    {

    }   

    public void printNode(int position)
    {

    }

    public void printAllNodes()
    {

    }

}
```

I have not been able to do this, and having tried several things over several hours, I have given up hope of being able to do it. If I don't find help here or still can't get these methods to work, I will be speaking with my instructor. It may simply be that I am overthinking the problem, and I hope that that is the case.

Comment: Why don't you try to work on each method implementation separately? Post what progress you have achieved since they are not really co-dependent.

Comment: Why would you have to compare int to E? I would start by writing the javadoc of the methods, to clarify what they should do and what each argument represents. For example, insertAfter should be documented as "inserts te given line after the line that is at position lineNum in the list. The given line will thus be at position lineNum + 1 in the list." You see that lineNum is thus a position in the list. It's not a line, and must not be compared with a line.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming  that your `Node` class looks like this :

```
class Node<E> {
  private Node next;
  private E value;
  [...]
}
```

You can add an attribute in your `DoublyLinkedList` class, in which you keep the number of `Node` that your list contains.

Then, if you want the Nth element of your list, you can do this :

```
private Node getNthElement(int n) {
   Node node = head;
   for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
      node = node.next;
   }
   return node;
}
```

These methods should also check if there are enough elements in the list, etc. But this is the main idea.